# How to get GET Request using Retrofit into listview

Tags: java, android, mysql

I need to pass a get request from my laravel API which contains a response as below.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "Brand": "honda",
            "Model": "CBR 200",
            "BikeNumber": "Ba 80 Pa 9029",
            "DatePurchased": "22/12/2016",
            "TotalKM": "1500",
            "user_id": 4,
            "created_at": "2020-05-20T07:17:21.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-05-20T07:17:21.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

The question I would like to ask is how do I pass get request using Retrofit in android and display it in a listview.

Do I have to use `Map<String, string>` in order to get the GET Request??

Comment: 'pass' isn't the same as 'parse'. Is this what was intended? Its a bit hard to pass/parse otherwise.

Comment: yes i intented parse

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a map you just need objects, you can do something like :

```
data class MyResponse(
        @SerializedName("success")
        val success: Boolean,

        @SerializedName("data")
        val data: List<Data>
)

data class Data(
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: Int,

        @SerializedName("Brand")
        val brand: String,
        ...
)
```

And with retrofit :

```
@Get("url")
fun getResponse(): Response<MyResponse>
```

Comment: I am actually trying this method but i cant figure a way to work this out but thanks for notifying me on map